# Metrization of the weak topology on the set of radon measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the set of Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$. We endow $\mathcal{M}$ with the the weakest topology such that $\mu \to \int f \, \mathrm{d} \mu$ is continuous for all $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, where $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of all real-valued continuous compactly supported functions. Is this topology metrizable? If we require that it holds for all $f$ bounded continuous real-valued functions, then I know that it is possible. But they don't generate the same topology...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The weak* topology of a dual Banach space is metrisable if and only if the underlying space is finite-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144475/weak-topology-of-x-is-metrizable-if-and-only-if). It seems to me, however, that you are interested in metrisability of the dual unit ball rather than the whole space. In this case, the answer is **yes** in the case of compactly supported continuous functions, and **no** in the case of all bounded continuous functions.

More specifically, the Banach space $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ of all continuous functions vanishing at infinity endowed with the supremum norm is separable, so the [dual unit ball is weak*-metrisable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352467/unit-ball-of-a-separable-banach-spaces-is-metrizable) Note that by the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) the weak*-topology of $C_0(\mathbb{R})^*$ is precisely the weak topology you have introduced above as $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is the completion of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ under the supremum norm.

When you consider all bounded continuous functions, you end up with the dual unit ball of a massive Banach space, namely $C(\beta \mathbb{R})$, which is very much non-separable, so the unit ball of $C(\beta\mathbb{R})^*$ is not metrisable.

Comment: $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ is not a Banach space under any natural norm. The completion with respect to the $\sup$-norm is $C_0(\mathbb{R})$, the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

Comment: Sure, I meant the dual under the sup-norm, which is the same as of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. I'll clarify this.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm actually interested in the space of all Radon measures. Or at least all Radon measures with mass 1 on the unit ball.

Comment: Then what does *Radon measure* mean for you? I think that it is commonly agreed that a Radon measure on a locally compact space $X$ is a measure which pops out in the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation of the dual space $C_0(X)^*$. Purely measure-theoretic definitions are rather tedious. As I said, if you consider metrisability of $C_0(X)^*$ in the weak*-topology, then there is no chance for that as $C_0(X)$ is infinite-dimensional. (This is a general fact in basic Banach space theory.)

Comment: I'm fine with this definition of Radon measure. But I only consider positive measures, and so this only "corresponds" to positive linear functionals on $C_c(X)$. The dual of $C_0(X)$ does also contain signed measure, so I had hope that the space of positive Radon measures is metrizable in the above mentioned topology. Perhaps I'm just confused, but I don't see why we can conclude by this result for the space of positive Radon measures.

Comment: The space of all positive Radon measures won't be metrisable either. The reason is that it is not first-countable. You see this modifying this proof: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623642/the-weak-topology-on-x-is-not-first-countable-if-x-has-uncountable-dim

Comment: @Tomek Kania: The space of positive Radon measures is metrisable (and even Polish) in contrast to the space of all Radon measures.